# Existence of a suitable smooth kernel

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Denote by $H=L^2([0,1])$ the Hilbert space of square integrable real valued functions  on the interval $[0,1]$. Does there exist a nontrivial smooth real valued function $k$ on the unit interval such that the bounded linear operator $T:H \to H$ defined by
$$ Tf(x)= \int_0^x k(x-s) f(s) ds$$
is a normal operator?

Comment: And you probably wanted to exclude $k=0$.

Comment: Such an operator would be pointwise dominated by a multiple of the Volterra operator. Doesn't this imply that the spectral radius is zero?